# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS VirtualBox VM stops at Black Screen before login

Tags: 20.04, graphics, virtualbox

My virtualbox VM has worked for a long time. Today, when I tried to boot it, it got stuck at a black screen just before the login screen (I see the ubuntu logo and loading circle thing, and then it goes away and the screen goes black).

I've tried increasing the #of CPUs to 2, every graphics adapter option in Virtualbox, enabling 3d Acceleration, disabling 3d acceleration,

Right now I have VBoxSVGA as adapter, 128mb vram, 3d acceleration off, 4gb ram and 2 cpus.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue.

For anyone having the same issue, it was lack of storage space. I had to expand my virtual hard drive, boot to a live virtual CD, and expand the partition size.